# Create iPA and APK remotely(without opening Dev tools) for both iOS and Android respectively

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, ipa

One of my client want to get my code and want that he himself create iPA and APK file without opening Dev tool like Xcode or Android Studio.
I've just found [this link for iPA](https://medium.com/xcblog/xcodebuild-deploy-ios-app-from-command-line-c6defff0d8b8), but I'm looking for some common tool which will work for both iOS and Android, so that he'll easily build. He doesn't own Mac machine but Window. Looking for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about an existing project, just run gradlew assembleDebug or gradlew assembleRelease from the root of the project, and the APK will be built.  If you're talking about creating a new project, I'd say just download Android Studio for Windows and create a blank project, alter it for each new one.

Answer (score 1):

For creating IPA he needs have a macOS based computer.

For either case you can create a script which packages in the android dev tools along with the Xcode dev tools. When he runs the script, it will create APK and IPA using the dev tools.